# Function has no effect for the first item in the array

Tags: php, arrays, session, shopping-cart

i have an function which change the quantity of product and store it back in the session.

```
public static function updateProduct($product_code, $newQty)
{   
    foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm) //loop through session array
    {
        if($cart_itm["code"] == $product_code) //the item exist in array
        {
            $product[] = array('name'=>$cart_itm["name"], 'code'=>$cart_itm["code"], 'qty'=>$newQty);
        }
        else
        {
            //item doesn't exist in the list, just retrieve old info and prepare array for session var
            $product[] = array('name'=>$cart_itm["name"], 'code'=>$cart_itm["code"], 'qty'=>$cart_itm["qty"]);
        }
    }
    //found user item in array list, and increased the quantity
    $_SESSION["products"] = $product;
return;
}
```

but if there are two or more products in the array, the function only works for the last added product.
Does someone have an Idea?

PS: The function for adding a product to the cart is working fine. But there aren't any big differences.

CODE for the comment:

```
$cart_items = 0;

foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm)
{       
echo '<input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="'.$product_code.'" />';           
$cart_items ++;
}

if(isset($_SESSION["products"]))
{
    echo '<form method="post" name="updateProduct">';

    echo '<ul>';
    $cart_items = 0;

    foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm)
    {
       $product_code = $cart_itm["code"];
        // get the product_name
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select($db->quoteName('product_name'))
         ->from($db->quoteName('#__osmaf_products'))
         ->where($db->quoteName('product_code') . ' = '. $db->quote($product_code));
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $result = $db->loadRow();

        echo '<li class="cart-itm">';
        echo '<h4>'.$result['0'].' (Artikelnr.:'.$product_code.')</h4>';
        echo '<label style="display:inline">Menge: </label><input type="number" style="width:50px;margin-top:9px" name="newqty" value="'.$cart_itm["qty"].'" />';
        echo ' <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="updateProduct" value="&#x21bb;" />';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="'.$cart_itm["code"].'" />';
        echo '</li>';
        $cart_items ++;

    }
}
```

When i now send the form everytime even which product i want to update, the last name and qty of the last product gets send to the function.

Comment: did you do `print_r($product);` before assigning to session in this function?

Comment: I got it! But it hasn't to do anything with the function... the problem is the product code:  LOOK ABOVE  here i got the right product code... but if the foreach loop is finish the product code is the code from the last one :/ Any Idea to solve this?

Comment: did you try the below solutions?

Comment: Look above please for the new code snippet that i added

Comment: Is this code for adding product code in hidden and passed to updateProduct function?

Comment: I think product_code is empty in foreach.

Comment: the hidden field with the name product_code is passed to the updateProduct function and it has the value that it should have(the right product code for each item). But i think the problem is at the form itselfs because the form is over the foreach loop and not in the foreach loop. This is so because i am using the form for formualar which also includes this fields.

Answer (score 0):

I changed a bit your code

```
public static function updateProduct($product_code, $newQty)
{   
    foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_item_id => $cart_itm) {
        if($cart_itm["code"] == $product_code) {
            $_SESSION["products"][$cart_item_id]["qty"] = $newQty;
        }

    }
}
```

Try it.

Comment: Please explain what you changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in this way you do not add items in the $product array but each time you re-initiate it. I would recommend to use [array_push](http://www.php.net/array_push) instead.

Comment: `[]` pushes an entry. The array would only be initialized if not existing.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you simple UPDATE the array, instead of copy everything?

note the `&` which will make `$cart_item` a reference instead of another copy.

```
public static function updateProduct($product_code, $newQty)
{   
    foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as &$cart_itm) //loop through session array, but as reference
    {
        if($cart_itm["code"] == $product_code) //the item exist in array
        {
            $cart_item["qty"] = $newQty;
            //assuming $product_code unique, so we are done.
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in comment, you are storing product code in hidden through loop with same name (Not array). and also, `$product_code` is not defined. Even defined before, the same value will be stored. So you have to store as array with all product code like as below

```
foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm)
{       
echo '<input type="hidden" name="product_code[]" value="'.$cart_itm["code"].'" />';           
$cart_items ++;
}
```

Comment: look at the comment at the main thread. The value is there. The form is the problem.

Comment: what is the purpose of placing form inside loop?

Comment: So got it. The Form should be used for the things first of all for all products and for changing the qty of one product. Now the complete <form>...</form> things are in this foreach so foreach item there would be this form and so i can get the right product number with the post format. Thanks for your help. You brought me to that point ;)

Comment: so you found solution?

Comment: Yees now i have two forms one in the foreach for changing the qty and one outside for the other form ;)